# Hibernate related logs in tomcat log files

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

I'm working on a project and recently we upgraded from tomcat7 to tomcat8. After that, some extra logging appeared in our application's log files even though we have never put those lines anywhere. Here's a sample of the log file:

```
2015-05-07T23:24:45.809Z DEBUG ClasspathScanner                    : Starting classpath scanning...
2015-05-07T23:24:45.813Z WARN  ClasspathScanner                    : No base packages specified - no classpath scanning will be done
2015-05-07T23:24:45.815Z DEBUG ClasspathScanner                    : Classpath scanning done
2015-05-07T23:24:46.065Z INFO  Version                             : Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final
2015-05-07T23:24:46.070Z DEBUG DefaultTraversableResolver          : Cannot find javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil on classpath. All properties will per default be traversable.
2015-05-07T23:24:46.072Z DEBUG ValidationXmlParser                 : No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only
2015-05-07T23:24:46.215Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    : Starting com.my.own.MyOwnConfigurationFile
2015-05-07T23:24:46.219Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    :    init()
2015-05-07T23:24:46.222Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    : Starting com.my.own.MyOwnConfiguration
2015-05-07T23:24:46.222Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    :    init()
2015-05-07T23:24:46.229Z INFO  MyOwnConfiguration                  : Config setting ==> LogLevel = INFO
2015-05-07T23:24:46.230Z INFO  MyOwnConfiguration                  : Minimum required OpenSSL version is: 1.0.2a. Please refer to catalina.out or catalina.log for the version of OpenSSL you are using.
2015-05-07T23:24:46.230Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    : Starting com.my.own.MyOwnLogSetup
2015-05-07T23:24:46.231Z DEBUG LifecycleManager                    :    init()
2015-05-07T23:24:46.231Z INFO  MyOwnLogSetup                       : Log level set to INFO
2015-05-07T23:24:46.585Z INFO  MyOwnBuildProperties                : Product: Test
2015-05-07T23:24:46.585Z INFO  MyOwnBuildProperties                : Version: 0.0.0.384.bf2ceed
2015-05-07T23:24:46.591Z INFO  MyOwnHttpsConnectionImpl            : Server at https://127.0.0.1:8080/
2015-05-07T23:24:46.591Z INFO  MyOwnConfigurationFile              : Read from /etc/MyOwnConfiguration.conf
2015-05-07T23:24:46.592Z INFO  SomeOtherConfiguration              : Port=12345
2015-05-07T23:24:46.592Z INFO  SomeOtherConfiguration              : ExternalUDPPort=23456
```

The ClasspathScanner, Version, DefaultTraversableResolver, ValidationXmlParser and LifecycleManager are not in my code.

They seem to be hibernate related but hibernate is not listed our pom file. Hibernate does exist in the generated classpath but it has been existed since the beginning of the project.

Does anyone have any idea where these logging come from and how to disable them?

Comment: I believe tomcat8 lib have some of them, check it the lib folder, to disable you need to configure log4j in your application or in tomcat-conf

Comment: Note that Hibnernate Validator is not the same as Hibernate ORM. And apparently its the reference implementation for Bean Validation. Maybe something else is using it.